# How to Concatenate a string in URL on Xcode (Objective-c)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to replace "CurrentLocation" with a value in following URL. "CurrentLocation" is a predefined string and it gives a dynamic value (I mean different name of location/city each time). I need help, How to do it in Objective-C ??

```
NSURL *MainURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.google.com/news?q=location:CurrentLocation&output=rss"];
```

In JavaScript i would do something like this;

```
var a="Google"; var b=".com"; var c=".np"; var d=a+b+c; document.write(d);
```

Please somebody help me with this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the the [stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) static message on the NSString class. This will create an *autoreleased* NSString object using the formatting you specify (using printf style format string). So for your case:

```
// get the current location from somewhere
NSString * yourCurrentLocation = @"Sydney";

// create your urlString %@ is replaced with the yourCurrentLocation argument
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://news.google.com/news?q=location:%@&output=rss", yourCurrentLocation];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried as you described, but sad thing is It says "too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2." :(

Comment: @Himalay You must have made a mistake copying this into your code. I did a verbatum copy and paste into my project and these lines compile. Try setting yourCurrentLocation explicitly (edited answer).

Comment: One more thing, how can i call a NSString value of "- (void)" into a "- (BOOL)" ?

Comment: @Himalay Glad you sorted it out. Not sure what you mean by that last comment, perhaps write it up as a new question with more information :).

Comment: @Himalay If you are happy with this answer, you can click the "accepted answer" tick to mark it as such ... welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

also, a good method is `stringByAppendingString`, here is more info in the apple site.

```
NSString *errorTag = @"Error: ";
NSString *errorString = @"premature end of file.";
NSString *errorMessage = [errorTag stringByAppendingString:errorString];
```